# Menu doesn't stick for the entire length of its container, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I'm using the following plugin:

https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem

The plugin is used for a horizontal menu on a gallery page so that when the user scrolls down past the menu, the menu will stick to the top of the browser window.

The problem is that sometimes when the page loads, I only get halfway down the page, and then it releases.

Other times I can get to the bottom of the page without any issues.

Almost all of the time, when I reload the browser (while on the page), the menu goes only half-way down from the top.

I'm assuming this has to do with the items in the containing div not fully loading, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here's how I call the jQuery:

In the footer I have:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

             //Start stickem Script
             $('.single-body').stickem();

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the plugin is calculating the container height before the images have loaded.  If you added width and height to your  tags that would solve the issue.

Otherwise you'd need to initialise the plugin after all the images have loaded.

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded is a great plugin for this.

```
$('.single-body').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $('.single-body').stickem();
});
```